# zend framework subquery

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

I am using zend framework 1.12. I have following query to run.

```
"SELECT name,(select count(*) from  org_quote_template_items where org_quote_template_items.quote_template_id = org_quote_templates.`id` ) as total_line_item FROM `org_quote_templates`"
```

In my model file , I created it like this. following is my model file.

```
    class default_Model_DbTable_QuoteTemplates extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Name of the original db table
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_name = 'org_quote_templates';


    public function getAllTemplate($where){
        $select = $this->select();        
        $subquery = " (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  org_quote_template_items WHERE org_quote_template_items.quote_template_id = org_quote_templates.`id` )";

        $select->from(array($this), array('org_quote_templates.*','total_line_items' => new Zend_Db_Expr($subquery)));

        $select = $select->where('organization_id = ?',$where['org_id']);

        $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($select);
        $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(
                Zend_Registry::get('config')->paginator->general);
        pr($adapter);
        exit;
    }
}
```

I am getting following error when I run the code.
" exception 'Zend_Db_Table_Select_Exception' with message 'Select query cannot join with another table' "

please let me know what should I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in your request. You should have:

```
    $select = $this->select ();
    $subquery = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  dtempls WHERE order_id = orders.id)";

    $select->from ($this, array (
        'id',
        'total_line_items' => new Zend_Db_Expr ($subquery)
    ));
```

Comment: ok, finally I go with joining the table but my need was that if it is possible to write sub query then it will be good.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use `setIntegrityCheck(false)` for accomplishing that. [Check this link](http://filip.forrez.net/2011/03/03/zend_db_select-select-query-cannot-join-with-another-table/)

Comment: I tried that bit stil getting error, the sub query is causing some problem. I did not find any answer how to use subquery in select statement in the zend framework !!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way in zend

```
$this->select()
->setIntegrityCheck(false)
->from(array('oqt' => 'org_quote_templates'),array('total_line_item'))
->joinLeft(array('oqti' => 'org_quote_template_items'), 'oqti.quote_template_id = oqt.id', array(count(*) as count))
```